# Python ForLoop Input

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically I have to create a function where I input 2 arguments:
the first one being a letter (i.e 'i')
the second one being a list (i.e ['trees', 'iron', 'cars', 'indian'])

my function should return every item in the list that begins with the same letter in my first argument.

so for I have:

```
def match_first_letter(G, F):
    for i in F:
        if i.F[0] == G:
            return F
```

where G is the first letter and F is the list

I keep getting:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'L'

Is there anything specific that I am doing wrong?

Comment: What do you expect `i.F[0]` to do?

Comment: Your error does not match your code.

Comment: i expect i.F[0] to go through each item in my list and return the those items that satisfy the argument

Comment: But `i.F[0]` is not an iteration. Why would you expect it to go through anything?

Answer (score 2):

First look at the line:

```
for i in F:
```

Here, you can access one element of `F` through `i` at a time.

So, you should use `i[0]` (first digit of i) rather than `i.F[0]`.

Secondly,

You are returning the `list`, not the matched value.

If you correct it, still you only have the first match even if you have multiple match.

That's because, you are returning immediately after first match.

You can achieve your expected output with a list comprehension.

```
def match_first_letter(G, F):
    return [i for i in F if i[0]==G]
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the loop you can say:

```
if i.startswith(G):
    yield i
```

You can call this function as:

```
matches = list(match_first_letter(F, G))
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you might do better to name variables sensibly. Instead of `G` and `F`, how about `letter` and `strings`? Your code is thus this:

```
def match_first_letter(letter, strings):
    for current_string in strings:
        if current_string.strings[0] == letter:
            return strings
```

In this case, the error that you have been seeing will instead say `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strings'`. Note that this matches the `current_string.strings` command.

`current_string[0]` is what you actually want to be testing against matching `letter`, as that is the first letter of the string `current_string`.

Finally, you're currently returning the list. Instead, you should add `current_string` to a list to be returned.

```
def match_first_letter(letter, strings):
    matched_strings = []

    for current_string in strings:
        if current_string[0] == letter:
            matched_strings.append(current_string)

    return matched_strings
```

Python actually has something called [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) which can do this kind of thing much more easily.

```
def match_first_letter(letter, strings):
    return [string_x for string_x in strings if string_x[0] == letter]
```

I'd recommend reading up on list comprehensions at the above link.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already saying `for i in F:` you can just say `if i[0] == G`. That is, access the zeroth element of i.

I believe you're trying to return `iron` and `indian` in the above example. See if something like this works for you.

```
arg1 = 'i'
arg2 = ['trees', 'iron', 'cars', 'indian']

def match_first_letter(G, F):
    for i in F:
        if i[0] == G:
            print(i)

match_first_letter(arg1, arg2)
```